# Scrapy HTTP Redirect 301 Issue

Tags: http, redirect, scrapy, http-status-code-301

I'm attempting to scrape a website and every child link I scrape is returning a HTTP 301 redirection response with no data in the response object.

> 2015-07-18 01:54:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (301) http://website.example> >(referer: http://website.example/tutorials/education/)

I've turned off following of redirects with meta tags in the scrapy request (meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [301]}).

With redirects turned on, the 301 response returns the same URL as the redirect request...

> 2015-07-18 02:00:52 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to http://website.example/tutorials/communications/20364/com-340-entire-course-mass-communication/> from http://website.example/tutorials/communications/20364/com-340-entire-course-mass-communication/>

Can you anyone give me any advice as to how to handle to HTTP 301 response in order to successfully scrape the page?

I've tried turning on/off redirect middleware and used an anonymous proxy with no luck.

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: check my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776048/scrapy-request-not-passing-to-callback-when-301 that fixed it for me, gotta keep trying different things tho.